# Publish my RESTful Web Service on the Internet

Tags: android, iphone, web-services, rest, tomcat

I developed a [RESTful Web Service using Jersey](http://www.vogella.com/articles/REST/article.html) between my `mySQL` server database and my Mobile Apps (Android, iPhone).

I used `Hibernate` in the Web Service to talk to the database and then wired my `DAOs` to the Jersey services.

My Operating System is Windows7-64bit.
Right now the Web Service is running on `Tomcat 7` in `locathost`. How can I publish my Web Service on the Internet? what is the best approach? for instance can I use Amazon Web Services or `Apache HTTP Server`?
Or perhaps other Web-Servers like :  [Web Servers - Examples](http://www.quackit.com/web_servers/tutorial/web_servers_examples.cfm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll just refer you to this:

[How to publish a JSP project on the Internet using Tomcat web server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4676003/how-to-publish-a-jsp-project-on-the-internet-using-tomcat-web-server/4676135#4676135)

Note, most providers frown on running servers on your home machine, but if you're not pushing crazy volume, it's likely not a big deal.

Addenda:

The premise is using your personal machine for the host. Using a service like DynDNS gives you a "presence" on the internet, since now you have a name that can be resolved. URLs that don't have a port number in them go to port 80, so you have to have your service configured for that port. This assumes you have a 100% connection to the internet, and that you can configure your networking hardware properly to accept and route the incoming traffic (beyond scope here).

ISPs frowning on running a server at home has nothing to do with Windows, it's more policy, infrastructure, pricing etc.

Answer (score 0):

It's a pretty big transition, but AWS can certainly help:

1. sign up
2. run up an instance - Windows if it will help keep things as consistent as possible for you
3. make sure you have the security settings for the instance set to allow port 80 traffic through (or other ports if you are using them)
4. set up the same tomcat and project on the new AWS instance you are running (you can probably zip and copy up just what you need)
5. make note of the DNS name for the service, or reserve and IP address (AWS feature) and point your own DNS entry to that ip address
6. test away.

Once you get more serious you might need load balancing, SSL security etc but probably not for your initial trials.