# How to host online a java web dynamic project created using jpa toplink, tomcat7 mysql and primefaces

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, toplink

I have managed to create my first JEE application. Now I am trying to publish it online, I tried openshift and Amazon EC2 tutorials  but none of them worked.

So is there another way to deploy it ?

[folder's tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/knI4X.png)

Comment: How are you currently deploying it?

Comment: if I correctly understand what you're asking , I deploy it locally (localhost)

Comment: Sorry, I missed the openshift part, you can always just zip your files and upload them to the folder structure.

Comment: use jboss tools plugin in Eclipse and directly deploy from there.

Answer (score 0):

If it's working locally then you're almost there.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4676003/how-to-publish-a-jsp-project-on-the-internet-using-tomcat-web-server) out. Will's answer should answer your question.

If you work for a company and have a server set-up there, you could reroute your domain to the company’s server and do the same. In this case, you can deploy your webapp on a virtual machine at port 80. This VM's IP address will be the one which your domain reroutes to.

The procedure is pretty much the same in both cases.

Comment: Very well, then try out Will's answer. It pretty much sums up everything. If there are any errors post it here and I'll try to help you out.