# How to publish Eclipse Dynamic Web Project on the internet (not localhost)?

Tags: tomcat, dns, web, server, publish

I have a dynamic web project with a .jsp, some java code which is called by scriptlets, which calls some database entries and so on. It runs great on my tomcat localhost server.

I want to publish this to the internet now (for free), just for purpose of practicing it. I don't want it to be safe, i don't need a high uptime or anything else, i just want to send a buddy the url to show it to him.

I tried AWS elastic beanstalk but for some reasons (have a running question on it) it doesnt work.

I found this: [How to publish a JSP project on the Internet using Tomcat web server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4676003/how-to-publish-a-jsp-project-on-the-internet-using-tomcat-web-server)

But somehow its too vague for me.

I have a Hostname and IP address from Dyndns.org.
I have Tomcat set up and it works locally on my machine.

In the description above i miss the point where i connect tomcat with the hostname and ip and whatever else i need.

Perhaps someone can give me better instructions how to set it up?

Answer (score 0):

Your router is the only one reachable from the internet and he knows the local address of your pc with tomcat.

One problem:
Everytime your router goes online, he gets an other ip, so you can't specify a static ip within dyndns.org. You can setup your router to login at dyndns.org everytime it goes online - this way dyndns knows the ip of your router!

Next problem:
The router is not the server and normally blocks requests from outside. So you have to forward a port to another ip within your local network - your server with tomcat.

I hope this will your tomcat going online as my tomcat on my raspberry pi. :)